# Data frame and summarizing

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My dataset:

```
dt<-data.frame(GrossIncome=seq(0, 10000, by = 1000),
               Turnover= seq(0, 100000, by = 10000),
               Sellers= seq(0, 1, by = 0.1),
               Buyers=seq(0, 1, by = 0.1))
```

So I now I want to summarize this data and divide by 1000 `GrossIncome` and `Turnover`.

```
     OUTPUT<-data.frame( 
                   "GrossIncome"=round(sum(dt$GrossIncome)/1000,1),
                   "Turnover"=round(sum(dt$Turnover)/1000,1),
                   "GrossIncomeAndTurnover"=round(((sum(dt$Turnover)+sum(dt$Turnover))/1000),1),
                   "Sellers"=round(sum(dt$Sellers),1),
                   "Buyers"=round(sum(dt$Buyers),1))


  Output                 
         GrossIncome Turnover GrossIncomeAndTurnover Sellers Buyers
1          55      550                   1100     5.5    5.5
```

So any suggestion for a more elegant solution then solution above ? I tried with the code below but this code only works for first two items (`GrossIncome` and `Turnover`) but not for rest of items.

```
  dt %>%
  dplyr::select(GrossIncome,Turnover)%>%
  dplyr:: summarise_all(sum,na.rm=TRUE)/1000
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `across()` to apply different functions to different columns.

```
dt %>%
  summarize(
    across(c(GrossIncome, Turnover), ~ round(sum(.) / 1000, 1)),
    GrossIncomeAndTurnover = GrossIncome + Turnover,
    across(c(Sellers, Buyers), ~round(sum(.), 1))
  )
#   GrossIncome Turnover GrossIncomeAndTurnover Sellers Buyers
# 1          55      550                    605     5.5    5.5
```

Note that in both our codes, the `GrossIncome` and `Turnover` summaries are computed first **and these newly created variables** are used in the `GrossIncomeAndTurnover` calculation. My code accounts for this, simply adding them.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
round_fun <- \(DF) {
  out <- apply(DF, 2, sum)
  out <- ifelse(out > 1e3, out/1e3, out)
  out <- c(out, out['GrossIncome'] + out['Turnover'])
  names(out)[5] <- 'GrossIncomeAndTurnover'
  return(out)
}
round_fun(dt)
# -------------------------------
> round_fun(dt)
           GrossIncome               Turnover                Sellers                 Buyers 
                  55.0                  550.0                    5.5                    5.5 
GrossIncomeAndTurnover 
                 605.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is first summarise all your data and then "format" it.

```
dt %>%
  summarise_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at(c("GrossIncome", "Turnover"), ~(.) / 1000) %>%
  mutate(GrossIncomeAndTurnover = GrossIncome + Turnover) %>%
  mutate_all(round, digits = 1)
```